# The scientific evidence of '4-7-8' breathing trick to induce sleep

Tags: sleep-deprivation, sleep-aids, oxygen, calm-soothing-strategies, induce

I read that a [simple '4-7-8' breathing trick can induce sleep in 60 seconds](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/science/science-news/11585755/Simple-4-7-8-breathing-trick-can-induce-sleep-in-60-seconds.html)

> **Simple '4-7-8' breathing trick can induce sleep in 60 seconds**.Dr
>   Andrew Weil says it works because it allows the lungs to become fully
>   charged with air, allowing more oxygen into the body, which promotes a
>   state of calm

But is there any scientific evidence behind this?

Comment: Why not take a time-out and [spend some time with the San people?](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/10/20151015-paleo-sleep-time-hadza-san-tsimane-science/) "The San and Tsimane languages have no word for insomnia, and when researchers tried to explain it to them, “they still don’t seem to quite understand,” Siegel says."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is no evidence](http://askforevidence.org/articles/breathe-deeply-and-nod-off):

"Despite a potential bit of miscommunication about the technique's effect on insomnia, there’s one thing I can be certain about – there doesn’t appear to be any reliable evidence that the 4-7-8 breathing method works."